# How to export data from Firebase Firestore emulator to actual Firebase Firestore database

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-cli

*Scenario:*

I am working on a POC locally where I am using Firestore as my database. As it is my local setup I am using Firestore Emulator. Now my POC is successful and I want to move local database from emulator to actual Firestore.

*Query:*

Is it possible to achieve what I am trying to do?

So far I am not able to find any relevant content on internet around this. I did find couple of examples where there is demonstration of exporting data from Firestore and importing to local emulator but I was not able to find the vice-versa option!

Answer (score 1):

Firebase does not provide any sort of tool or service to do this.  Your easiest alternative will be to write a program to query the data out of the emulator and write it into your cloud hosted instance.  You might find the Firebase Admin SDK helpful for writing to the cloud in a program that you run locally.

Comment: Thanks for response Doug! Wat you have mentioned does make sense. However I was thinking of alternative way - Emulator exports data as *.overall_export_metadata*. Is there any way to export that data in JSON format? What I was thinking is - if I get JSON data handy, I can use third party packages like *node-firestore-import-export* package to import data to datastore.

Comment: That file is not documented.  If you want to take a crack at decoding it, that's entirely up to you.  Probably easier to just make queries you already know.